# Hard drive malfunctions when other hard drives are connected

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ubuntu-10.04

I have a SATA drive that worked fine. Then I installed two more hard drives into my system. When these hard drives are installed, if I try to access the SATA drive in Linux, it will start lightly clicking and then the drive will become unavailable. If I power on the machine without the other two hard drives then it works fine. What could be causing this to happen? I don't think it's heat because the two hard drives are far away from the SATA drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The light clicking you hear from your hard drive is produced by it's spindle motor when it cannot get enough current. Looks like your power supply is not powerful enough for three hard drives.